# Setting android:layout_toRightOf= causes textview to disappear

Tags: xml, android-layout, android, android-xml

I'm attempting to set two textviews side by side:

- `userVideouploaderTextView`
- `userVideoviewsTextView`

However if I set `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userVideouploaderTextView"` of `userVideouploaderTextView`, I got an issue.

`userVideoviewsTextView` disappears.

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.idg.omv.ui.widget.UrlImageView
        android:id="@+id/userVideoThumbImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="YouTube video thumbnail"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userVideoTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:text="Video Title Not Found"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn1"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userVideouploaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userVideoviewsTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userVideouploaderTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="11dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your view `userVideouploaderTextView` has `width="fill_parent"` change to `wrap_content` or fixed dp